# How to link libstdc++ statically with clang++

Tags: llvm, clang, static-linking

I'm trying to learn C++ deeper by reading source of STL as well as debugging it, so I want to link `libstdc++` statically to my program, and it works fine using `g++`. However, how can I achieve the same thing with `clang++` in llvm?

In another way, the question is, what is the `clang++` equivalent of `-static-libgcc`?

`Makefile` I'm using

```
CXX=g++
CC=g++
LDFLAGS=-g -O0 -static-libgcc
CFLAGS=-O0 -Wall
CXXFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: I don't think static linking is what you need. You need to have debug information for the library, no matter whether it's static or dynamic. You can find this in different places in different Linux distributions; some have static library with debug information, some have unstripped shared library somewhere, some have just debug information for the shared library (e.g. Debian/Ubuntu usually do this).

Comment: I have tried in g++, and static linking works, and I guess it is because my libstdc++.a is not stripped while libstdc++.dylib is. Do you mean I should find a shared library which is not stripped?

Answer (score 5):

The flag you're looking for, in both GCC and Clang, is: `-static-libstdc++`

Comment: This gives a warning "argument unused during compilation: '-static-libstdc++'" in Clang 4.2.

Comment: clang++ version 4.2.1 on CentOS 7 says

`clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-libstdc++'`

and static linking does not occur - is there any way to fix it?

Comment: This is a link-time flag, not a compile-time flag. If you look at the question, the `-static-libgcc` flag is added to the `LDFLAGS` variable, which is where this one should be added as well.